# "Need be" vs. "Needs to be"

Tags: word-usage, writing-style, phrase-usage

I've written the following in a sentence, but now that I look at it, I'm doubting my grammatical instincts and wanted to get a second opinion.

> ...the balance need be swayed only slightly...

Is the use of "need be" here correct?  I read this as essentially identical to:

> ...the balance needs to be swayed only slightly...

but I haven't been able to find any other written uses of the first syntax.  Formal references for this usage would be appreciated, but more general comments are of course welcome.  Thanks!

Comment: It is difficult to tell because you have not given complete sentences. Grammar depends partly on context.

Comment: I can hardly say the [*word need be used*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22word+need+be+used%22), since that's 395 written instances without it. But Google Books claims to have 1,140 instances pointing out that the [*word needs **to** be used*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22word+needs+to+be+used%22). Without ***to***, it seems rather dated to me.

Comment: If you inflect to *needs*, it is no longer a modal so needs the *to*.  If you do not, it does not.

Comment: @tchrist Basically you are saying that "It needs be" is incorrect, but "It need be" or "It needs to be" are correct?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both are fine. *Need*, like *dare*, is sometimes called a "semi-modal", in that it can be used like modals (eg *can*, *may*) but can also be used as a normal verb (eg like *want*).

So *The balance need be swayed only slightly* is parallel to *The balance can be swayed only slightly* (the meaning is different - this is just showing the syntax); whereas *The balance needs to be swayed only slightly* is parallel to *The balance requires to be swayed only slightly*.

I believe that the modal use is becoming less common, and I suspect it is altogether less common in US English than in UK, but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: Excellent point, my mind automatically jumped to the idiomatic usage. That being said, "need be" denotes necessity and "can be" denotes either limit or option, no? That is, doesn't the usage "need be" express that "the necessary 'amount of sway' that the balance requires is 'slight'"; whereas the usage "can be" expresses that "the degree to which it is possible to 'sway the balance' is 'slight'"? That is, the first formulation tells us what is the threshold and the second formulation tells us what is the limit.

Comment: Sure. I was using _can be_ only as a syntactic parallel: I didn't mean to suggest that it was similar in meaning. I'll edit to show this.

Answer (score -1):

In "it needs to be....." / "it need to be......"  need is used as a verb not as a modal auxiliary. Because, with no modal auxiliary we use "to be", right?

So, it should be "it needs to be...."always which means "needs" here is the s form of NEED.